# How should package authors produce composer.lock for lower PHP version than locally installed?

Tags: php, composer-php

Consider this `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.0",
    "symfony/console": "^2.6|^3.0",
    "react/event-loop": "^0.4",
    ....
}
```

Best practice says `composer.lock` should be committed. But- if the package developer's machine e.g. runs php7- how should a compatible lock file be produced? `--prefer-lowest` may be a possible approach but could also skip compatible bug fixes that may be desired.

Comment: It depends if you intend to support backwards compatibility. Assuming your package supports 7.x I don't necessarily expect it to run on 5.x simply because of the differences in the language itself. Say you're using `strict_types` in your files, that immediately breaks any compatibility with 5.x.  My 2¢

Comment: Sorry if not clear- the package is supposed to support >=5.6 as in the json above. The code is already written accordingly. The question is only referring to how to handle composer.lock for this case.

Comment: *"Best practice says composer.lock should be committed."* -- only for the project. It doesn't help committing `composer.lock` for libraries. Composer doesn't use `composer.lock` of the dependencies, it uses only the top-level `composer.lock`, the one of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found in the composer github issues at https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6757

In the system-wide `config.json` composer allows to specify the `platform` like this:

```
{
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.6"
    }
}
```